# CustomMessageBox doesn't adapt when entering text

Tags: windows-phone-8, keyboard, messagebox

I've got a problem with a `CustomMessageBox` in Windows Phone. Normally when you got a page with several textboxes, then the view gets adapted/scrolled when a textinput starts.

But in a `CustomMessageBox` it seems no to work. It still adapts/scrolls the mainview, which is now in the background.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new CustomMessageBox()
        {
            Content = new FeedbackView(),
            RightButtonContent = "Cancel",
            LeftButtonContent = "Send",
            VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
            HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        };

        dialog.Show();
    }
}
```

I made a little example: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6B27FD720F1FB58D!16324&authkey=!AKsq3XzgjQviN8w&ithint=folder%2csln

Does have anyone an idea to get this to work or do you think that I have to do this manually by myself?